# Effect of weight decay on loss

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, loss-functions

I am new to deep learning and the terminology "L2 regularization" and "weight decay" seems to be used almost interchangeably... L2 regularization however modifies the loss function by adding a term, while weight decay **does not modify the loss** and instead decays the weights during the weight update.

Is this correct?

Comment: Whether or not weight decay is equivalent to L2 regularization depends on the optimizer you're using. This is addressed in the linked thread, with links to supporting articles.

Comment: Thanks, I think that in the case of AdamW it does not modify the loss.